# jsPDF in Wordpress causing uncaught Type error (Cannot read property 'length')

Tags: wordpress, canvas, jspdf

**Hey I'm working on a Plugin in wordpress printing individial PDFs.
On my own XAMPP everthing works fine, but know i got this error.**

I generate a QR code with the Google API and a canvas function to convert that image into base64 for jsPDF.

But in the Console I got this Error Message

But I dont know what is wrong that the jsPDF Libary genrate this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at Object.jsPDFAPI.binaryStringToUint8Array (jspdf.debug.js:4197)
    at Object.jsPDFAPI.addImage (jspdf.debug.js:4395)
    at createPDF ((index):303)
```

This is my code:

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying single airdrop post type
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#single-post
 *
 * @package airdrop
 */

get_header(); ?>

<?php
do_action( 'airdrop_wrapper' ); ?>

<?php
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.1.1/jspdf.umd.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.2/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://platin-grading.de/wp-content/plugins/airdrop/templates/image.js"></script>
    <div class="table">
        <div class="row">

        <div class="airdrop-thumbnail-wrap col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">

            <figure class="airdrop-thumbnail">
                <?php if( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                    echo '<a rel="bookmark" href="'. esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '">';
                    the_post_thumbnail( 'airdrop-main-thumbnail' );
                    echo '</a>';
                }
                ?>


            </figure>
        </div>
        <?php
        $name_pokemon                   = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'name_pokemon', true );
        $code_pokemon                   = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'code_pokemon', true );
        $lang_pokemon                   = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'lang_pokemon', true );
        $setname_pokemon                = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'setname_pokemon', true );
        $zustand_pokemon                = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'zustand_pokemon', true );
        $zustand_zahl_pokemon           = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'zustand_zahl_pokemon', true );
        $code_card_pokemon              = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'code_card_pokemon', true );
        $value_centering                = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'value_centering', true );
        $value_corners                  = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'value_corners', true );
        $value_edges                    = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'value_edges', true );
        $value_surface                  = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'value_surface', true );
        $post_id                        = $post->ID;


        ?>



        <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
            <table class="airdrop-single-summary" style="width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <i class="fas fa-user" style="font-size: 30px; color: #00b359;"> </i>
                        <h1 class="airdrop-name" style="padding-left: 15px;"> <?php echo esc_textarea( $name_pokemon ); ?></h1>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <!-- Airdrop Token Symbol -->
                <tr>
                    <td><span class="airdrop-symbol"><i class="fas fa-language"  style="color: #00b359"></i> <?php _e( "Sprache", 'airdrop' ); ?></span></td>
                    <td><?php echo esc_textarea( $lang_pokemon ); ?></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><span class="airdrop-req"> <i class="fas fa-user-friends" style="color: #00b359"></i> <?php _e( "Name des Sets", 'airdrop' ); ?></span></td>
                    <td><?php echo esc_textarea( $setname_pokemon); ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><span class="airdrop-symbol"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"  style="color: #00b359"></i> <?php _e( "Veroeffentlicht im Jahr", 'airdrop' ); ?></span></td>
                    <td><?php echo esc_textarea( $code_pokemon ); ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><span class="airdrop-req"> <i class="far fa-comment" style="color: #00b359"></i> <?php _e( "Zustand (Worte)", 'airdrop' ); ?></span></td>
                    <td><?php echo esc_textarea( $zustand_pokemon) ; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><span class="airdrop-req"> <i class="fas fa-star-half-alt" style="color: #00b359"></i> <?php _e( "Zustand (Zahl)", 'airdrop' ); ?></span></td>
                    <td><?php echo esc_textarea( $zustand_zahl_pokemon) ; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><span class="airdrop-symbol"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"  style="color: #00b359"></i> <?php _e( "Veroeffentlicht im Jahr", 'airdrop' ); ?></span></td>
                    <td><?php echo esc_textarea( $code_pokemon ); ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><span class="airdrop-req"><i class="fas fa-barcode"  style="color: #00b359"></i> <?php _e( "Kartencode", 'airdrop' ); ?></span></td>
                    <td><?php echo esc_textarea( $code_card_pokemon); ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><span class="airdrop-req"><i class="fas fa-star"  style="color: #00b359"></i> <?php _e( "Bewertungen (falls vorhanden)", 'airdrop' ); ?></span></td>
                    <td><?php echo  esc_textarea( "Centering: " .$value_centering); ?><br>
                    <?php echo  esc_textarea( "Corners: " .$value_corners); ?><br>
                    <?php echo  esc_textarea( "Edges: " .$value_edges); ?><br>
                    <?php echo  esc_textarea( "Surface: " .$value_surface); ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><span class="QR-Code">Qr-Code:</span></td>

                    <?php
                            $string = get_permalink();
                            $link = utf8_decode($string);

                    ?>
                    <td><img id="qr" src="<?php echo 'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl='.$link.'&choe=UTF-8'?>" title="Link to PGS" crossorigin="anonymous" alt="QR-Code"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>


            <button onclick="createPDFextra()">Print with Extra</button>
            <button onclick="createPDF()">Print normal</button>

            <script type="text/javascript">

                let qrUrl = '<?php echo 'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl='.$link.'&choe=UTF-8'?>';
                let qrCode;

                function getDataUrl(img) {
                    // Create canvas
                    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                    // Set width and height
                    canvas.width = img.width;
                    canvas.height = img.height;
                    // Draw the image
                    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
                    return canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
                }
                // Select the image
                const img = document.querySelector('#qr');
                img.addEventListener('load', function (event) {
                    const dataUrl = getDataUrl(event.currentTarget);
                    qrCode = dataUrl;
                    console.log(dataUrl);
                });

            </script>


            <script>

                // Default export is a4 paper, portrait, using millimeters for units
                function createPDF(){

                    const doc = new jsPDF({
                        orientation: 'p',
                        unit: 'mm',
                        format: 'a4',
                        putOnlyUsedFonts:true,
                        floatPrecision: 0 // or "smart", default is 16
                    });

                    doc.text("Etikett:", 10, 10);


                    doc.rect(10,20,63,20);  //rectangle above
                    doc.rect(10,40,63,20);  //rectangle below

                    doc.addImage(img_logo, 'JPEG', 10, 41, 18, 18);    //Add Logo
                    doc.setFontSize(6);
                    doc.text("<?php  echo $code_pokemon . " " . $setname_pokemon ?>", 30, 43);   //Add Year and Setname of Card
                    doc.text("<?php  echo $lang_pokemon ?>", 30, 45);   //Add Language
                    doc.text("<?php echo "#" . $code_card_pokemon . " " . $name_pokemon?>", 30, 47);    //Add Cardcode and Name

                    doc.setFontSize(30);
                    doc.text("<?php  echo $zustand_zahl_pokemon?>", 63, 50, 'center');        //Add Number in BIG
                    doc.setFontSize(6);

                    doc.text("<?php  echo $zustand_pokemon ?>", 63, 53, 'center');            //Add Number as word



                    //Rückseite


                    doc.addImage(qrCode, 'PNG' , 11, 21, 18, 18);            //Add QR-Code
                    doc.text("<?php  echo $post_id ?>", 22, 21,null,180);                    //Add POST-ID

                    doc.text("www.platin-grading.de", 55, 21,null,180);                    //Add Website URL

                    doc.save("test.pdf");

                    doc.output('dataurlnewwindow', 'test.pdf');
                }



                // Default export is a4 paper, portrait, using millimeters for units
                function createPDFextra(){

                    const doc2 = new jsPDF({
                        orientation: 'p',
                        unit: 'mm',
                        format: 'a4',
                        putOnlyUsedFonts:true,
                        floatPrecision: 0 // or "smart", default is 16
                    });

                    doc2.text("Etikett:", 10, 10);


                    doc2.rect(10,20,63,20);  //rectangle above
                    doc2.rect(10,40,63,20);  //rectangle below

                    doc2.addImage(img_logo, 'JPEG', 10, 41, 18, 18);    //Add Logo
                    doc2.setFontSize(6);
                    doc2.text("<?php  echo $code_pokemon . " " . $setname_pokemon ?>", 30, 43);   //Add Year and Setname of Card
                    doc2.text("<?php  echo $lang_pokemon ?>", 30, 45);   //Add Language
                    doc2.text("<?php echo "#" . $code_card_pokemon . " " . $name_pokemon?>", 30, 47);    //Add Cardcode and Name
                    doc2.setFontSize(4);
                    doc2.text("CENTERING: ", 30, 53);
                    doc2.text("<?php  echo $value_centering ?>", 40, 53);   //Add value of center
                    doc2.text("CORNERS: ", 45, 53);
                    doc2.text("<?php  echo $value_corners ?>", 55, 53);   //Add value of center
                    doc2.text("EDGES: ", 30, 55);
                    doc2.text("<?php  echo $value_edges ?>", 40, 55);   //Add value of center
                    doc2.text("SURFACE: ", 45, 55);
                    doc2.text("<?php  echo $value_surface ?>", 55, 55);   //Add value of center




                    doc2.setFontSize(30);
                    doc2.text("<?php  echo $zustand_zahl_pokemon?>", 63, 50, 'center');        //Add Number in BIG
                    doc2.setFontSize(6);

                    doc2.text("<?php  echo $zustand_pokemon ?>", 63, 53, 'center');            //Add Number as word



                    //Rückseite


                    doc2.addImage(qrCode, 'PNG' , 11, 21, 18, 18);            //Add QR-Code
                    doc2.text("<?php  echo $post_id ?>", 22, 21,null,180);                    //Add POST-ID

                    doc2.text("www.platin-grading.de", 55, 21,null,180);                    //Add Website URL







                    doc2.save("test.pdf");

                    doc2.output('dataurlnewwindow', 'test.pdf');
                }



            </script>




        </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php

    the_content();
    the_post_navigation();

    // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
    if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) :
        comments_template();
    endif;
endwhile; // End of the loop.
?>

    <!-- #primary -->
<?php do_action( 'airdrop_wrapper_close' ); ?>

    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/27b0ded188.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<?php
get_footer();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no clue why it worked now...

I changed the code to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

                let qrUrl = '<?php echo 'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl='.$link.'&choe=UTF-8'?>';
                let qrCode, qrCode2;


                function getDataUrl(img) {
                    // Create canvas
                    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                    // Set width and height
                    canvas.width = img.width;
                    canvas.height = img.height;
                    // Draw the image
                    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
                    return canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
                }
                // Select the image
                const img = document.querySelector('#qr');
                qrCode2 = getDataUrl(img);
                console.log(qrCode2);

                img.addEventListener('load', function (event) {             //Dead Code
                    const dataUrl = getDataUrl(event.currentTarget);
                    const dataUrl2 = getDataUrl(img.getAttribute('src'));
                    qrCode = dataUrl;

                    console.log(dataUrl);
                    console.log(qrCode);
                    console.log(dataUrl2);
                    //document.writeln(qrCode2);
                    //document.writeln(dataUrl2);



                });

            </script>
```

So i think the function of getting the image into canvas was wrong and the empty string causing the error in jsPDF